# Get Top entries from a table based on some criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Lets say "TopicComments" which records each comments from every user on a topic. The table has TopicID and UserID as foreign  keys and comment date and comment text. So for each user comment, there will be a record with TopicID, UserID, DateTime, and text.

i want to retrieve the topics with most amount of comments within lets say 5 days. Im not the guy with best SQL skills, so im kind of stuck here. Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if my question makes too much sense.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not mentioning the RDBMS, lets say MS SQL

```
SELECT  TopicID,
        COUNT(1) TotalCount
FROM    TopicComments
WHERE   CommentDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY TopicID
ORDER BY TotalCount DESC
```

So a **full example** would look something like

```
DECLARE @TopicComments TABLE(
        TopicID INT,
        UserID INT,
        CommentDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @TopicComments SELECT 1, 1, '14 Feb 2010'
INSERT INTO @TopicComments SELECT 1, 1, '14 Feb 2010'
INSERT INTO @TopicComments SELECT 1, 2, '14 Feb 2010'
INSERT INTO @TopicComments SELECT 1, 2, '14 Feb 2010'

INSERT INTO @TopicComments SELECT 2, 1, '14 Feb 2010'
INSERT INTO @TopicComments SELECT 2, 1, '14 Feb 2010'
INSERT INTO @TopicComments SELECT 2, 2, '05 Feb 2010'

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT  @StartDate = '10 Feb 2010',
        @EndDate = '14 Feb 2010'

SELECT  TopicID,
        COUNT(1) TotalCount
FROM    @TopicComments
WHERE   CommentDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY TopicID
ORDER BY TotalCount DESC
```

Results

```
TopicID     TotalCount
----------- -----------
1           4
2           2
```

To select the *TOP 1* would then be

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        TopicID,
        COUNT(1) TotalCount
FROM    @TopicComments
WHERE   CommentDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY TopicID
ORDER BY TotalCount DESC
```

**EDIT**

Use somthing like

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME

SET     @EndDate = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())) --returns only the date part of GETDATE()
SET     @StartDate = @EndDate - 5
```

Comment: thanks, seems so easy now :) . How do i do it using @startDate=GetDate() and @enddate will be GetDate()-n days?

Answer (score 0):

You should use *GROUP BY* in you sql statement to group all comments by TopicID and than do sum()

Something like that^

> SELECT TopicID, sum(UserID) from
>   TopicComments WHERE DateTime > *date
>   with 5 days offset*  GROUP BY TopicID
>   ORDER BY sum(UserID);